# How do I use groups 'depends-on' in my testng.xml config file?

Tags: testng

I am using IntelliJ-IDEA 14.x and TestNG 6.8.17, but when I try to use the `depends-on` attribute, I get the folllowing error:

```
Element dependencies is not allowed here
```

And here is my `testng.xml` config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="My Regression Suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="15">
    <test name="My suite">
        <groups>
            <dependencies>
                <group name="c" depends-on="a  b" />
                <group name="z" depends-on="c" />
            </dependencies>
        </groups>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**What could possibly be wrong??**  Is there any way to debug this?  I copied this code straight from the TestNG documentation site.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by a different version of the DTD which is delivered through IntelliJ's TestNG plugin (TetsNG-J). I have no idea why this is done, since the DTD should be downloaded from the TestNG server.
IntelliJ in fact does contact the TestNG server for the DTD, but still imports the DTD found in the plugin JAR located in JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\testng\lib folder.
Although not a clear solution, you might exchange the DTD found in the JAR for the one available at http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd . This effectively removes the error message, but the problem might arise again in a future release of the TestNG-J plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I do not get the above said error with 6.8.17 as well (m using eclipse).
But,
whenever you are using groups, you need to specify what tests need to be included in the test as well.  Just groups doesn't work.

eg.

```
<test name="DOD Check">
        <groups>
            <dependencies>
                <group name="c" depends-on="a  b" />
                <group name="z" depends-on="c" />

            </dependencies>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="testngtests.TestDependsGroups"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
```

Comment: I did that, yes.  Left it out for brevity.  It doesn't solve the issue for me though.  I also tried on a completely different computer, also using IntelliJ-IDEA 14.  Also tried various versions of TestNG.